# How to know all the sass partials files used in one html page

Tags: sass, source-maps

I have a huge site with a lot of sass partials getting processed in one single css file. We are also using sourcemap for debugging the styles.

Is it possible in the browser to get a list of the used sass partials files for a given html page ?

thanks!